# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'path'

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

[I am trying a create pdf in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zar2B.png)

package name: syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^19.4.47-beta

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exclamation mark after the final closing parentheses, so it looks like `())!.path`

Comment: The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'List<Directory>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'path', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'path'.                                                                                        Now I'm getting error like this